# Firebase: Set Multiple Documents within Collection from JSON - automatically add the UserID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I have the following:

```
FoodSample.forEach((doc) => {
firebaseConfig.firestore().collection("customers").doc().set(doc);
})
```

FoodSample is my JSON file which looks like:

```
[{
    "Category": "BREAKFAST",
    "Name": "Bacon",
    "Weight": "0.4"
},
{
    "Category": "BREAKFAST",
    "Name": "Eggs",
    "Weight": "0.1"
}]
```

This works well, but in the set I also want to add the userID as a field on every record (id.user.uid) - how do I set this field in the set(doc) or alternatively how do I add this to the JSON. I cannot manually add it to the JSON as every user will be different upon sign up.

EDIT:

I can do something like:

```
const res = {
...FoodSample,
message: FoodSample.map(el => ({
...el,
User: id.user.uid,
}))
}
```

I could then use this res as my array - but I don't want the array in 'message' - just modifying the existing array?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) when executing different calls to an asynchronous method in parallel.

If I correctly understand your question, the following would do the trick:

```
const promises = [];

FoodSample.forEach(obj => {
    obj.user = id.user.uid;
    promises.push(firebaseConfig.firestore().collection("customers").add(obj));
});

return Promise.all(promises);
```

---

Note that [`add({...})`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) is the same than `doc().set({...})`.

Comment: Hey @PaulVI, did you have the time to look at my answer. Does it answer your question?